# Tensorflow bazel build failing - not generating bazel-bin directory

Tags: tensorflow, ubuntu-16.04, cudnn

I'm trying to install Tensorflow from the source using the following configuration:

- NVIDIA GTX 1070
- UBUNTU 16.04
- CUDA 8.0
- Cudnn v5.0

I have followed the following steps from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/get_started/os_setup.md):

- installed bazel
- installed dependencies
- installed CUDA support
- `./configure` with CUDA 8.0 support
- `bazel build -c opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package`

After this step, to my knowledge, there should be a `bazel-bin` directory, so that I can subsequently execute

```
$ bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/tensorflow_pkg

# The name of the .whl file will depend on your platform.
$ sudo pip install /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-0.10.0rc0-py2-none-any.whl
```

However, there is no such directory.

I have a feeling this error message might have something to do with it?

```
ERROR: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_clone/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/BUILD:45:1: error while parsing .d file: /home/volcart/.cache/bazel/_bazel_volcart/62dff5ffffc63bcd8a9350984645e0be/execroot/tensorflow_clone/bazel-out/local_linux-opt/bin/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/_objs/python/ops/_lstm_ops_gpu/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/kernels/lstm_ops_gpu.cu.pic.d (No such file or directory).
nvcc warning : option '--relaxed-constexpr' has been deprecated and replaced by option '--expt-relaxed-constexpr'.
In file included from third_party/gpus/cuda/include/cuda_runtime.h:78:0,
                 from <command-line>:0:
third_party/gpus/cuda/include/host_config.h:115:2: error: #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 5.3 are not supported!
 #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 5.3 are not supported!
```

Upon re-executing `bazel build ...` I found this...

```
WARNING: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/util/python/BUILD:11:16: in includes attribute of cc_library rule //util/python:python_headers: 'python_include' resolves to 'util/python/python_include' not in 'third_party'. This will be an error in the future.
```

I should also add this...

```
$ bazel version
Build label: 0.3.1
Build target: bazel-out/local-fastbuild/bin/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/BazelServer_deploy.jar
Build time: Fri Jul 29 09:09:52 2016 (1469783392)
Build timestamp: 1469783392
Build timestamp as int: 1469783392
```

Comment: "gcc versions later than 5.3 are not supported!" sounds like a very clear error message to me.....

Comment: @talonmies agreed, my only doubt was that it included a path to the `contrib` directory. Although, I guess that could still cause the entire thing to fail, trying a different version now

Comment: @talonmies turned out to be a permissions issue -- Doh! Always seems to be a permissions issue `sudo bazel build ...`

Answer (score 1):

`bazel build -c opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package`

Caused a permissions issue. Added `sudo`

`sudo bazel build -c opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package`